# MiKTeX consistently failing macOS

Tags: pdftex, miktex, compiling, command-line

I am trying to install MiKTeX on a new macOS system. Each time that I try to compile any .tex file, I get the following error:

```
jwalsh23@Jacks-MacBook-Pro-14 $ pdflatex CV.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 22.1) (preloaded format=pdflatex.fmt)
 restricted \write18 enabled.

Sorry, but pdflatex did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  /Users/jwalsh23/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/data/miktex/log/pdflatex.log
```

The specified logfile contains the following:

```
2022-05-18 19:04:30,819-0400 INFO  pdflatex - this process (3654) started by bash in directory /Users/jwalsh23/Downloads with command line: pdflatex CV.tex
2022-05-18 19:04:30,819-0400 INFO  pdflatex - this is MiKTeX-PDFTEX 4.10.0 (1.40.24) (MiKTeX 22.1)
2022-05-18 19:04:30,819-0400 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
2022-05-18 19:04:30,823-0400 INFO  pdflatex - going to create file: pdflatex.fmt
2022-05-18 19:04:30,837-0400 INFO  pdflatex.core - forking...
2022-05-18 19:04:31,168-0400 ERROR pdflatex - /Users/jwalsh23/bin/miktex did not succeed; exitCode: 1
2022-05-18 19:04:31,169-0400 ERROR pdflatex - output:
2022-05-18 19:04:31,169-0400 ERROR pdflatex - 
Sorry, but: The executed process did not succeed.

2022-05-18 19:04:31,169-0400 FATAL pdflatex.core - The memory dump file could not be found.
2022-05-18 19:04:31,169-0400 FATAL pdflatex.core - Data: fileName="pdflatex.fmt"
2022-05-18 19:04:31,169-0400 FATAL pdflatex.core - Source: Libraries/MiKTeX/TeXAndFriends/texmfapp.cpp:717
2022-05-18 19:04:31,169-0400 FATAL pdflatex - The memory dump file could not be found.
2022-05-18 19:04:31,169-0400 FATAL pdflatex - Info: fileName="pdflatex.fmt"
2022-05-18 19:04:31,169-0400 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries/MiKTeX/TeXAndFriends/texmfapp.cpp
2022-05-18 19:04:31,169-0400 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 717
2022-05-18 19:04:31,170-0400 INFO  pdflatex - this process (3654) finishes with exit code 1
```

I have tried reinstalling MiKTeX several times, running `miktexsetup cleanup`, I've tried using an admin installation as well as a user installation, nothing seems to work.

Comment: any particular reason to be using miktex here? the vast majority of mac users will be using mactex (texlive) so easier  to get help  when things go  wrong.

Comment: Welcome to SE. I wouldn't choose MikTeX as a distribution for macOS, honestly. If someone else can't help you find what specific problem you have, I'd recommend installing MacTeX instead.

Comment: you need to find out, why the format can't be created. There should be a log for it in one of the roots (on windows I have them in `....\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\makefmt\pdflatex`)

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this problem once when I update the MiKTeX. Finally, I figured it out that You have to give "miktex console" administrate authority. The solution is:

run you "MiKTeX Console.app", then choose operation mode as administration mode instead of user mode, update packages and so on.

Then, the app should work as before.